# nested path dosent work in react router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a browser router for my app but the nested paths are not working.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider
} from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}>
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      {/* ... etc. */}
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On this code both `"localhost:3000/"` and `"localhost:3000/dashboard"` are opening the `HomeScreen` page only.
Can you tell me what I should do to make `"/dashboard"` open `LoginSrceen` instead of `HomeScreen`?

Comment: I think you just forgot to add `/` so it should be `/dashboard`

Comment: <Route path="/"><Route index element={<HomeScreen />}/>
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      {/* ... etc. */}
    </Route> please try like this

Comment: Also it's better to use `exact` for exact matches, such as 
`<Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<LoginScreen />} />`

Comment: @Sowmiya Thanks it worked anyways do you have any idea why the above code isnt working even though i have copied it form https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router documentation only?

Comment: It initially check path '/' have any elements. if '/' has any element then it will go to that element. In your code , you give path '/' with homescreen element. So it goes to homescreen. To avoid that you have to use 'index' to show homescreen. Please Check in browser developer tools , login screen may be there inside homescreen component if you are using outlet

Comment: @697 `"/"` isn't necessary when building relative routes, and the `Route` component hasn't any `exact` prop in RRDv6. Your comments are more applicable to RRDv5, which the OP clearly isn't using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are nesting routes then the parent route necessarily needs to render an `Outlet` component for nested routes to render their `element` content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomeScreen = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ... Home screen UI ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    ...
  );
};
```

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<HomeScreen />}>
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      {/* ... etc. */}
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the off-hand chance that you ***actually*** want `HomeScreen` and `LoginScreen` to render each on their own discrete routes, then they should not be nested one in the other, but instead should be rendered as sibling routes. Render `HomeScreen` on an index route such that it will be rendered when the URL path matches the parent route, e.g. `"/"`.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/">
      <Route index element={<HomeScreen />} />
      <Route path="dashboard" element={<LoginScreen />} />
      {/* ... etc. */}
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </div>
  );
}
```